# Some problems with appending in json c++

Tags: c++, json

I am using the jsoncpp library in c++ to parse and create json structures. I'm trying to write json file. I'm expecting this:

```
[
  {     
    "student" : {
        "name" : "Julia",
        "math" : [
                   { 
                     "grade" : 10,
                     "day" : 23 
                   },
                   { 
                     "grade" : 10,
                     "day" : 23 
                   }
                 ]
    }
  }
]
```

my code:

```
Json::StyledWriter writer;
Json::Value val;
ofstream f("out.json", ios_base::out);
unsigned int c = 0;
        val[c]["student"]["name"] = "Julia";
        val[c]["student"]["math"] = Json::Value(Json::arrayValue); <== at this I'm opening [] brackets
        val[c]["student"]["math"].append( {"grade":10, "day":23} ); <== and this I'm stuck, I've got an error, because I don't know how to do it right
```

In the future it's suppose to be a lot of students and they should have a lot of marks.

Comment: I would imagine it's the same process as the outer object you're filling in.

Comment: You should edit your question and include the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: I saw how it works on phyton and I did the same thing, but it did'n work, ok then, the error message is unexpected "{"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about jsoncpp,
but how about trying this?

```
...
    Json::Value element(Json::objectValue);
    element["grade"] = 10;
    element["day"] = 23;
    val[c]["student"]["math"].append(element);
...
```